# page animation on scrolling it like movie

Tags: javascript, css, animation, scroll

I found this page http://www.wanderworld.io/ when you scrolling its start animation on scrolling and scenes are changing. how to create something like this? Please help me, any example on jsffidle or codepen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To point you in the right direction, this is called parallax scrolling and can be accomplished using `CSS`, but is most commonly done in `Javascript` / `jQuery`.

This library is great for parallax animation and would probably accomplish most, if not all, of what the example site does: http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/

Basically the idea is to have a page scroll listener that tracks the `window.scroll` position. At certain ranges, elements move in and out of the screen. The concept behind it is relatively simple, but it can be difficult to implement and can be as complicated as you choose to make it.